# What happens if you declare new primitive variables to a class whose instances are persisted in cache?

Tags: java, caching, serialization, redis, deserialization

```
class Car {
    private String brandName;
    private String modelName;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

I persisted 10 car Objects(eg: (Nissan, Rouge), (Bmw, X3)) to redis cache server.
I now modified Car class by adding new primitive variables.

```
class Car {
    private String brandName;
    private String modelName;
    private int length;
    private boolean convertible;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Now after deploying new code to App server, what happens when I have a code that gets Car object from Redis server and reads the new primitive variables.

```
int lengthOfCar = (Car)(RedisCache.get(key)).getLengthOfCar();
boolean isConvertible = (Car)(RedisCache.get(key)).isConvertible();
```

what happens when persisted objects get deserialized? It cannot be null as it is a primitive object.

Comment: It depends on how Redis is caching your objects. But if it is via Object serialization, the serialized objects on Redis will get a versioning error when you try to reconstruct the object

Comment: No way to tell from this much code without knowing how your objects are stored.

Answer (score -1):

I was using fasterxml ObjectMapper to deserialize the object https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

And after few tests I realized that it is able to deserialize primitive datatypes.

Comment: Actually ... that's probably not the issue.  The issue will be whether the JSON -> POJO mapping is dealing with POJO fields that don't have corresponding JSON attributes.

Comment: no, if you look at readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType) method inside ObjectMapper it handles that conversion.

Comment: You are missing my point.  Of course the mapper can convert primitive types.  That surely was never in any doubt.

Comment: It is the mapper that identifies missing fields and translates it to default primitive types.

Comment: So ... when you say  (in your answer) *"it is able to deserialize primitive datatypes"*, you actually mean something like "it is able to fill in default value for primitive fields which are missing from the serialization".  I hope you can **now** see that what you wrote says something very different from what you meant.   The point of answering is that people reading your answers can understand what you are *actually* trying to say.